# Dynamic Rest Client in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, client, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a dynamic Rest client, where I can set the HTTP Method(GET-POST-PUT-DELETE), Query Params and body(Json, plain, XML), this is basically what I need, for the request I think i know how I can do it, but my concern is for reading the answer, since I know what I should get ( format) but I dont know how to read it properly, so far I return an object, below the code (only for POST, but the idea is the same):

```
        Response responseRest = null;
        Client client = null;
        try {
            client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().establishConnectionTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).socketTimeout(TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

            WebTarget target = client.target(request.getUrlTarget());
            MediaType type = assignResponseType(request.getTypeResponse());
                switch (request.getProtocol()) {
                    case POST: {
                        if (request.getParamQuery() != null) {
                            for (VarRequestDTO varRequest : request.getParamQuery()) {
                                target = target.queryParam(varRequest.getName(), varRequest.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                        responseRest = target.request().post(Entity.entity(new ResponseWrapper(), type));
                        break;
                    }
                    default:
                    //HTTP METHOD No supported
                }

                Object result = responseRest.readEntity(Object.class);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            response.setError(Boolean.TRUE);
            response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (responseRest != null) {
                responseRest.close();
            }
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
        }
```

What I basically I need is to return the object in the format needed, and where is called it's supposed to do a cast to the correct format, I just need it to be dynamic and used for any service.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every request that a ReST client makes to a ReST service, it passes an "Accept" header.

This is to indicate to the service the MIME-type of the resource the client is willing to accept.
In the above case, what are the acceptable formats (json/ plain text/ etc.) for you?

Depending on the "accept" format you choose, and the "Content-type" header that you receive, you can write a deserializer to accept that data and process.

Also, instead of returning an Object which is too generic, consider returning a readable Stream to the caller.

Comment: Well, the accetable formats are json, plain text and xml, but if you are talking about the request I dont have any problem with it, the thing is with the response, I need the response to be the type is sent in the request, but I can create an Object for a JSON for example because at that point I dont know the class, so I'm thinking of returning an object, and then where it's called they do the cast, but I dont know is if a good solution

Comment: Updated my answer